# Using HTTPClient to connect to site on same server - getting Connection refused

Tags: java, linux, shell, tomcat, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a tomcat 5.0 server running various applications on a Unix server.
On this same server, I have a shell script that uses org.apache.commons.httpclient and connect to a URL on one of the applications.
This has worked for years.

I have moved the applications to a Virtual Linux server and Tomcat 6.0.
Now when I run the shell script, I get:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

When I update the URL to an application on a different server, my shell scrip completes successfully.

Why can’t I run my shell script and access the website running on the same server?
And what can I do to make this work?

Comment: Add your code, what did you try/have yourself?

Comment: in situations like this your CLI is your best tool going for you 

if you can ssh to the box and from command line try a few tests that are all similar or even a simple ping www.yoururl - its possibly down to iptables running on the local machine that is stopping this from happening - you could try adding the existing hostnames/ips to /etc/hosts of this local machine - but if iptables has some funny rule in place about local http traffic then thats what needs to be changed

links http://yoururl OR

lynx http://yoururl

Comment: When you run your script, are you trying to connect to localhost, 127.0.0.1, or the actual IP of the box?  If you're trying to connect to localhost, make sure localhost is defined correctly in your /etc/hosts file.  Alternatively, try connecting to the actual IP of the box, rather than 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Comment: I am on a server called webappsdev, it’s IP is 10.7.3.130

From the server I access http://webappsdev.emera.com/ using org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient 

I can ping the site:

webappsdev$ ping webappsdev.emera.com
PING webappsdev.emera.com (10.7.3.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from webappsdev (10.7.3.130): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms

I can access the URL from anywhere on my network, except for when I try to access it while on this server.
Seems like some kind of loopback issue being prevented by the server

Comment: I am connecing using the IP of the box, not localhost

Comment: Outgoing connection-block from a software firewall? What happens is you use `localhost`?